# Complete Cyclic Quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

Consider cyclic $ABCD$ with centre $O$. Let $AD$ and $BC$ meet at $P$. Let $AB$ and $DC$ meet at $Q$. Let $X$ be the intersection of the diagonals $AC$ and $BD$. Prove that $OX \perp PQ$.

**EDIT:** Prove that $O$ is the orthocentre of triangle $PQX$. 
[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $t_A, t_B, t_C, t_D$ be the lines tangent to the circumcircle $k$ of quadrilateral $ABCD$ at the points $A, B, C, D$ respectively. Let $$R = t_A \cap t_C \,\, \text{ and } \,\, S = t_B \cap t_D$$ Then, by Pascal's theorem applied to the degenerate hexagon $AABCCD$, the points $P, Q, R$ are collinear, i.e. $R \in PQ.$ Analogously, by Pascal's theorem applied to the degenerate hexagon $ABBCDD$, the points $P, Q, S$ are collinear, i.e. $S \in PQ.$ Consequently, the four points $P, Q, R, S$ are collinear, i.e. $P,\, Q \, \in \, RS$.

Denote by $P_1$ and $P_2$ the points of tangency of the two tangent lines to the circle from point $P$ and denote by $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ the points of tangency of the two tangent lines to the circle from point $Q$. By polarity, the polars of points $R$ and $S$ with respect to the circle are lines $AC$ and $BD$ respectively, which means that the intersection point $X = AC \cap BD$ is the pole of line $RS$. Consequently, the polar of any point from $RS$ is a line passing through $X$. In particular, the lines $P_1P_2$ and $Q_1Q_2$ are the polars of points $P$ and $Q$ respectively, where $P$ and $Q$ lie on $RS$, so both polar lines $P_1P_2$ and $Q_1Q_2$ pass through the pole $X$.

Let $U = t_A \cap t_B \,\, \text{ and } \,\, V = t_C \cap t_D$. 
Then, by Pascal's theorem applied to the degenerate,
self-intersecting hexagon $AACBBD$, the points $P, U, X$ are
collinear, i.e. $U \in PX.$ Analogously, by Pascal's theorem
applied to the degenerate hexagon $ACCBDD$, the points $Q, V, X$
are collinear, i.e. $V \in PX.$ Consequently, the four points $P,
Q, R, S$ are collinear, i.e. $P,\, Q \, \in \, RS$.  Consequently,
the four points $P, U, X, V$ are collinear, i.e. $P,\, X \, \in \,
UV$.

By polarity, the polars of points $U$ and $V$ with respect to the circle are lines $AB$ and $CD$ respectively, which means that the intersection point $Q = AB \cap CD$ is the pole of line $UV$. Consequently, the polar line of any point from $UV$ is a line passing through $Q$. In particular, the line $P_1P_2$ is the polar of point $P \in UV$, so the polar line $P_1P_2$ passes through the pole $Q$. However, we already know that $X \in P_1P_2$ so it turns out that the four points $Q, P_1, X, P_2$ are collinear. Absolutely analogous arguments lead to the conclusion that the four points $P, Q_1, X, Q_2$ are also collinear.

We are now ready to conclude that, since $PP_1$ and $PP_2$ are the two tangent lines to the circle through the point $P$, with $P_1$ and $P_2$ the two points of tangency, the line segment $PO$ is the orthogonal bisector of the chord $P_1P_2$. However, $Q, X \in P_1P_2$, so $QX \perp PO$. Analogously, since $QQ_1$ and $QQ_2$ are the two tangent lines to the circle through the point $Q$, with $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ the two points of tangency, the line segment $QO$ is the orthogonal bisector of the chord $Q_1Q_2$. However, $P, X \in Q_1Q_2$, so $PX \perp QO$. As a result of this, we have proved that the lines $PO$ and $QO$, being orthogonal to the segments $QX$ and $PX$ respectively, are two altitudes of triangle $PQX$. Consequently, $O$ is the orthocenter of triangle $PQX$ and therefore the line $OX$ is the third altitude of the $PQX$, i.e. $OX \perp PQ$.

Comment: +25 for the effort!

Answer (score 1):

Let $O(0,0)$, $A(r\cos\alpha,r\sin\alpha)$, $B(r\cos\beta,r\sin\beta)$, $C(r\cos\gamma,r\sin\gamma)$ and $D(r\cos\delta,r\sin\delta)$.

Now, write equations of lines $AB$, $AC$, $AD$, $BC$, $BD$ and $CD$, find coordinates  $P$, $Q$ and $X$, find $m_{PQ}$, $m_{OX}$ and prove that $$m_{PQ}m_{OX}=-1.$$
It's very ugly, but it's the proof.

By the way, after getting the coordinates of $P$ we can get the coordinates of $Q$ and $X$ in a similar way,

id est, we can write these coordinates immediately.

The same words we can say about equations of lines $AC$, $AD$, $BC$, $BD$ and $CD$ after getting equation of $AB$.